In which episode did Marshall make the Taken Movie Reference
I've been trying to find this How I Met Your Mother episode where Marshall says something like

I don't have money but I have a wife who has a very specific set of skills.

Can Anyone tell what particular episode that was?

This appears to be Episode 13 of Season 5 titled Jenkins. This dialogue appears around 3:15. The exact dialog is:

My wife knows I'm here.
She doesn't have money, but what she does have is a very special set of skills.

This was a reference to Taken dialog which was 

I don't know what you want. If you are looking for ransom, I can tell you I don't have money. But what I do have is a very particular set of skills; skills I have acquired over a very long career. Source

As per Wikia page

When Jenkins is asking Marshall if he is a Vikings fan and he is concerned that she may be out to get him, he says his wife "doesn't have money, but what she does have is a very special set of skills" in reference to Liam Neeson's character in Taken.


Ahhhhh!!!!! Fastest gun in the west!

By 18 seconds! Hats off to you, sir.
